# From Win7 Enterprise logon screen, how to know other logged-on?

Tags: windows-7, windows, login-screen, credentials

Current security policy for a MS ADS domain is for a user session to lock after a short amount of inactivity.  For a few machines, multiple people use them throughout the day.

The problem is that the logon screen does not show anyone logged-on, so it is hard for a user to remember if they logged off without logging back on.  Since there can be a session open with a user editing a database, we are very reluctant to force logoff.  In fact, the brain dead app will often block the logout process.

The [pGina](https://github.com/pgina/pgina/wiki/FAQ) project is now compatible with Windows 7 "Windows Credential Provider", but i was hoping there was a built-in GPO without resorting to third party solutions. There has to be a way in Win7 Enterprise to do something that WinXP home did.

Comment: The lock screen should show who is logged in, if it doesn't, thats a group policy.

Comment: When that is shown, it only shows one user out of many.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can configure it to lock the computer in such a way only one user is allowed at a time.  i mean I deal with locked stations all the time and have to go find the person that locked it to unlock it.

Comment: Only one user at a time would not work.  Staff is already too crunched for time.

Comment: "something that WinXP home did". Are you referring to the Fast User Switching, where it shows all usernames, then text if that user is logged in? Or the Lock screen where only that user or an administrator can log in?

Comment: @CanadianLuke, All Usernames would solve this.

Comment: Windows 7 does this but on another screen. If you click "switch user" on the lock screen and then go to the log in window it will show all users that have a session imo

Answer (score 0):

If you know the computer name you should be able to do this remotely.  Check this site: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntadmincommands.php